# Is it necessary to reload stylesheet when appending div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I'm using django, bootstrap, select2, jquery for my problem.

This is the original template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block scripts %}
{% load static %}
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="{% static "myscript.js" %}"></script>

    <link href="{% static "select2/css/select2.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{% static "select2/css/select2-bootstrap.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="{% static "select2/js/select2.min.js" %}"></script>

{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<form id="formid">
    <select id="selectionid" class="form-control" >
        <option selected>Seleziona una squadra:</option>
        {% for team in league.Teams %}
            <option value="{{ team.id }}">{{ team.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
</div>


<div id="resultdiv">
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

When the option in select changes I use this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectionid").on("change", function(){
        $("#resultdiv").load(address)
    };
});
```

to return a page with this html:

```
<div>
    <select class="js-example-basic-single">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now if I don't include again the stylesheets, I don't see the select rendered properly.

```
{% block scripts %}
    {% load static %}

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="{% static "myscript.js" %}"></script>

    <link href="{% static "select2/css/select2.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{% static "select2/css/select2-bootstrap.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="{% static "select2/js/select2.min.js" %}"></script>

{% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
    <div>
        <select class="js-example-basic-single">
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Now, this code is a bit simplified for sake of clarity.

Am I doing something wrong or reloading the stylesheets is normal in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: But here I'm reloading the same files. Furthermore if I put my  `<select class="js-example-basic-single">` code in the main page it has the correct aspect. If I load it with jquery it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

few questions to clarify your question

your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#rosa_selection").on("change", function(){
    $("#result_listing").load(address)
};
```

});

1) check the semicolon I'm not sure its the result of rewriting it in here or a copy paste but semicolon is missing from ".load()".

2) you are referring to "id" in these selectors but the html you are injecting is referring to class , check it just in case

some points that maybe cause this:
1) how do you append the div :
creating a new element giving it a div attributes and then appending it via element.appendChild(newElement); after setting it to the wished identifiers? or pure html injections innerHTML += ...?

From what i know unless you need some JavaScript to do some style compiling (many frameworks use this) then when injecting a new element it might happen AFTER the run-flow of the script changes everything and this div won't be applied unless you'll explicitly do it.

Comment: (1) doesn't matter, but (2) is where the problem lies.

Comment: The names of ids where wrong, but yes I'm referring to ids. With the new names might be clearer. I simply want to substitute the content of `<div id="resultdiv"></div>` Why that would affect the rendering obliging to reload the stylesheets? I don't know how to answer to your other question, I'm kind of new to all this. I'm using `load` to get the html, isn't it enough?

Comment: @KevinBrown what do you mean "is where the problem lies"?

Comment: I was quoting your point. I found the problem anyway: I need to call this `$(".js-example-basic-single").select2();` inside the html I'm loading with jquery `load`. I can't load it in the same function wrapper which calls `load`, right?